# How do you repair a Ubuntu 14.04 RAID-LVM-DM-CRYPT-LUKS Physical to Virtual system that won't boot?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, lvm, luks, dmcrypt

I can't get a Ubuntu 14.04 Virtual server to boot correctly.
It's recently been cloned "dd if=/dev/sda of=vmimage"
The Physical has a RAID1-LVM-DMCRYPT-LUKS configuration,
The boot sequence aborts and drop to the BusyBox shell.

```
Begin: Waiting for encrypted source device
```

I can see above the message that it was unable to find any volume groups.

```
No volume groups found
```

I suspect this is due to the raid not starting up correctly.

Looking at /proc/mstat indicates that md0 is active and md1 is inactive

I have to stop md1, and force it with --run to start

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md1
mdadm --assemble /dev/md1 /dev/sda2 --run
```

I am now able to mount partitions on /dev/md0 and unlock the dmcrypt volume manually if I so desire.

If I exit the shell, it tries to unlock the dmcrypt container, but still fails to boot.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you really only copy one of the two disks?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by booting with one virtual disk cloned from two physical disks.
After manually booting, you could try this if you have md0 uncrypted and md1 crypted :

vi /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/workaround_mdadm :

 `#!/bin/sh
 sleep 5
 mdadm --stop /dev/md1
 mdadm --stop /dev/md0
 sleep 5
 mdadm --assemble --scan`

Note : Feel free to change the sleep values as well.

Make the file executable :
chmod 755 /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/workaround_mdadm

Create new initrd files in /boot :
update-initramfs -k all -c

Reboot with your virtual disk and check if you are prompted for a passphrase.